# How to wait for state change in react-router onEnter?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, single-sign-on, redux-saga

I've been trying to use `react-router`'s `onEnter`hook to check authentication.
Basically, I dispatch a saga action on the Redux store to initiate SSO login on the `onEnter` hook.

However, even though I get redirected successfully for authentication, this happens just after the components get mounted, so there's a flicker.
I tried checking for the authentication state before calling the `callback` on the `onEnter` hook, but that didn't work either.

I apply the hook as:

```
<Route path='home' component={HomePage} onEnter={checkAuthentication(store)} />
```

and then I implement it:

```
const checkAuthentication = (store) => {
  return (nextState, replace, next) => {
    if (!store.getState().authentication.isAuthenticated)
       store.dispatch(checkAuth())
    return next()
  }
}
```

In my sagas, I have:

```
const isAuthenticated = yield call(getAuthenticationToken) // returns a promise which resolves when the user has successfully authenticated on the SSO page
yield put(actions.checkAuthSuccess(isAuthenticated))
```

How can I make sure that no components mount unless the saga returns the authentication status?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the saga is asynchronous. The authentication check is being delegated to the event loop and then executed after the protected component mounts/updates. The best way that I have found to deal with this situation is to create a route and component that acts as a gatekeeper for protected routes.

Basically instead of initially routing to your protected component, send them first to a component with a loading modal (or blank or whatever). From there, when the authentication logic is complete they will be routed either to the protected route or booted back to where they came from.

If your users need to be routed a lot this isn't a viable solution and it is better to find a way after the first authentication check to make that check synchronous. That way you can use the onEnter without it first rendering the component.

One solution is to use a callback as the 3rd parameter for the onEnter method.

[Here is a good thread that discusses how to use that functionality](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3671)

In your case, it looks like it would be that **next** argument. You would have to take that and call it after the authentication check is resolved.

Comment: Also, what version on react-router are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ej-mason, I'm using react-router v3.
Also, your idea of redirecting the users to another component displaying a spinner might be a viable solution and I like it.

I could even try to wrap this logic inside a HOC and show the spinner/loader there but I thought that since I'm calling the _next_ callback after the state indicates the user is authenticated, I shouldn't face this pre-loading of the components, even with the async saga.

Comment: Because of how the async event loop works, next is being called before the saga gets executed. The async function has to wait until all synchronous code finishes and is then run.

Comment: Okay, so I get the problem. But I was wondering if there was a solution for it other than creating a spinner component or something. Can't I pass around the next callback to the saga? If so, how?

Comment: A couple of things I can think of off the top of my head is, pass that next callback function into checkAuth as an argument. then use call to invoke it after the put statement in your saga. you will also need to add an else statement in your checkAuthentication method and call next there if the user doesn't need to checkAuth.

Comment: You could also get rid of the sagas, simplify the redux logic and use promises or async/await to control when that next function is invoked. Then add the dispatch inside there after a successful authCheck.